# Azure Blob Source Error: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-blob-storage

I have created Data Flow Task in SSIS and configured Blob storage container.My request to process from Azure Blob to SQL server.I am getting "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request" exception while executing SSIS.

I have verified the connectivity and access in Azure.

[execution error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eq5hX.png)
[No debug error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TON0P.png)

Comment: do you want to copy one file or all the files in blob to SQL Server? Can you show us any screenshots or more details?

Comment: Did you use the account and access key to access the blob storage ?

Comment: Attached screenshot in above, kindly verify and advise.

Comment: I am trying load flat file data  from azure blob storage  --> azure sql server using SSIS

Comment: Hi @Meena, I got it. Just from your second screenshot, you get the in progress but the data flow works well and the data have been load to SQL Server successfully, am I right?

Answer (score 2):

@Meena

You need to add two Key to windows registry

To use TLS 1.2, add a REG_DWORD value named SchUseStrongCrypto with data 1 under the following two registry keys.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319

This works.

Answer (score 0):

Just from your second screenshot, you get the error in progress but the data flow works well and the data have been load to SQL Server successfully, am I right?

I tried the same SSIS package(Load data from Blob to SQL Server) but has no error. Please try delete and reset the Azure Blob Source.

Test the connection when we create the source:
[image]

Azure Blob Source editor:

[image]

Progress:
[image]

Just from your progress error, we can not find which cause the 400 bed request error. But We can try re-create the source again to check if it will happen again. And most of all, the data flow task works well and all the data loaded to SQL Server correctly.

Comment: Hi Yue, I am trying to ready flat file ".txt" file. From the above screenshot i could see that you are reading csv file

Comment: Hi Yue, Even I tried download task using csv file but i am getting same error.I am using free trial version .  1. Created new storage account 2. created new container 3. uploaded csv file.4. In SSIS created Azure download task to download the csv file in local (to verify ).

Comment: Hi @Meena, that's very strange, we can not repeat the same error. I use Visual Studo 2019 to create the SSIS package, and it works ok.

Comment: Hi Yue, I am using free trial version. do we need to change any access level in azure storage account to access this file.

Comment: @Meena Yeah, please make sure you have the permission to access the file.