# "Azure Blob Source 400 Bad Request" when using Azure Blob Source in SSIS to pull a file from Azure Storage container

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-storage

My package is very simple. It is loading data from a csv file that I have stored in an Azure storage container, and inserting that data into an Azure SQL database. The issue is stemming from the connection to my Azure storage container. here is an image of the output:

[image: Output]

Making this even more odd, while the data flow task is failing:

[image: Task Failure]

The individual components within the data flow task all indicate success:

[image: Component Successes]

Setting up the package, it seems that the connection to the container is fine (after all, it was able to extract all the column names from the desired file and map them to their destination). Here is an image showing the connection is fine:

[image: Test Connection]

So the issue is only realized upon execution.
I will also note that I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63928437/azure-blob-source-error-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-400-bad-request) post that was experiencing the *exact* same issue that I am now. As the top response there instructed, I added the new registry keys, but no cigar.

Any thoughts would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure your blob can be access by public:

[image]

And if you don't have requirement to set networking, please make sure:

[image]

Then set the container access level:

[image]

[image]

And make sure the container is correct.